# redhat linux sudo su - failed

Tags: redhat, sudo, selinux

I am no more able to do sudo su - to get root authentication. I am logged in as test user. I mapped test from unconfined_u to SElinux user staff_u. I restarted the vm machine on google cloud. I can login to vm as test user, but if I do sudo su -, I get following error:

su: avc.c:74: avc_context_to_sid_raw: Assertion `avc_running' failed.
Aborted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known bug of CentOS and Redhat:

> **0011249: su: avc.c:74: avc_context_to_sid_raw: Assertion `avc_running'
> failed.**
>
> Description   Whenever I execute a su - command after switching
> into the sysadm_r, I get this fault. The system is in enforcing mode
> when I get this error. When in permissive mode, this does trigger the
> error. Attempted to address the problem with audit2allow to see if
> that could temporarily resolved the problem while I looked for a
> permanent solution but that did not work either

There are the 2 referencies:

- [Centos bug](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=11249)
- [RedHat Bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1688887)